# Can light orbit an object that is NOT a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, orbital-motion

I know that light can enter into an unstable circular orbit around a black hole, at a distance of its innermost bound circular orbit (IBCO) $\frac{3r_s}{2}$ where $r_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius of the black hole (assuming a non rotating uncharged black hole). In addition, as far as I understand it, for the case of black holes any light which crosses to a point below the IBCO will spiral into the black hole. I am wondering about an object with a radius $r_s < r < 1.5r_s$. Such an object would not be a black hole, as it’s radius is larger than its Schwarzschild radius. However it seems like light would still be able to form unstable orbits around it as the IBCO would be outside the surface of the object, and also if any light were to cross the IBCO it would still be forced to spiral into the surface of the object. Am I misunderstanding the mechanics of something or is such an object really possible? If it is possible, do they exist in nature?

Comment: The exterior region of a collapsing star is equivalent to Schwarzschild, so light can definitely orbit it at $1.5 r_s$ even if the horizon hasn't formed yet.